# Syntax error near unepected token do

Tags: linux, bash, while-loop

This is my code for a bubble sort on n numbers:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n  "Input n, the number of numbers"
read N
declare -a array[N]
echo -e "Input the elements, press enter after each element"
for i in seq 1 $N  
do 
    read array[$i]
done

swap1()
{ # for swapping two numbers, we are employing bubble sort
    local temp = ${array[$1]} 
    array[$1] = ${array[$2]}
    array[$2]=$temp
    return
}

numb_elements=${#array[@]}
let "comparisons = $numb_elements - 1"

count=1

while [ "$comparisons" -gt 0]
do
   index =0

   while[ "$index" -lt "$comparisons" ];do
      if [ ${array[$index]} \> ${array[ 'expr $index + 1']} ]
      then 
         swap1 $index 'expr $index + 1'
      fi
      let "index += 1" # Or, index+=1 on Bash, ver. 2.1 or newer
   done

   let "comparisons -=1"
   echo 
   echo "$count: ${array[@]}
   echo

   let "count +=1"
done
exit 0
```

I have two problems with this code:

1. the input array just takes 3 numbers
2. and then i get an error on line 42 saying syntax error for the command while do

I have tried `while [] ; do`, but it doesn't work.

Its just been a day that i have been trying bash syntax.

Comment: your script is full of syntax errors. With Shellscript you must take care of spaces: <bash>while[1]; do echo bye; sleep 1; done</bash> is an error; <bash>while [ 1 ]; do echo bye; sleep 1; done</bash> it's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a series of errors:

- correct spaces are fundamental to shell scripting
- missing `` apices to execute code and get the output
- logic error (starting inserting from the second array element and using it from the first one)
- iterating the wrong number of time for the bubblesort alg

This is your code corrected.

```
#!/bin/bash

swap1() { # for swapping two numbers, we are employing bubble sort
        local temp=${array[$1]}

        array[$1]=${array[$2]}
        array[$2]=$temp
        return
}


echo -n "Input n, the number of numbers: "

read N
declare -a array[$N]

echo -e "Input the elements, press enter after each element"
for i in `seq 1 $N`
do
        read array[$i]
done

numb_elements=${#array[@]}
#let "comparisons = $numb_elements - 1"
comparisons=$numb_elements
count=1
while [ "$comparisons" -gt 0 ]
do
        index=1
        while [ "$index" -lt "$comparisons" ]
        do
                tmp=`expr $index + 1`
                if [ ${array[$index]} -gt ${array[$tmp]} ]
                then 
                        swap1 $index $tmp
                fi
                let "index += 1" # Or, index+=1 on Bash, ver. 2.1 or newer
        done
        let "comparisons -= 1"
        echo
        echo "$count: ${array[@]}"
        echo
        let "count += 1"
done

exit 0
```

Comment: error on line 34, in the while loop [ while( $comparisons" -gt 0] says integer expression expected

Comment: numb_elements=${#array[@]}
#let "comparisons = $numb_elements - 1"
comparisons=$numb_elements

Answer (score 2):

Moreover do not write

```
for i in seq 1 $N
```

which iterate i over the set {"seq","1",$N}, but type

```
for i in $(seq 1 $N)
```

to insert the result of the command as part of code.

You forgot the closing quote in this line :

```
echo "$count: ${array[@]}
```

Also the code of the nested loops is badly indented, so it is a bit hard to read and debug.

Answer (score 2):

So far I have found the following errors:

```
while [ "$comparisons" -gt 0 ]
                            ^ missing space here

while [ "$index" -lt "$comparisons" ];do
     ^ missing space

echo "$count: ${array[@]}"
                         ^ missing quote
```

Note that in bash `[` is equivalent to `test` command, so a space is required around `[` and `]` unlike many other programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
while [ "$comparisons" -gt 0]
```

should be (notice space before the closing bracket `]`):

```
while [ "$comparisons" -gt 0 ]
```